# postman apps into nodejs, how it works?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, backend, postman

I am still new to learning backend, I think I skipped too quick and I'm trying to push or simple post or call `?` `or request ?` to `localhost:3333/api/notify`but using or implement in `node.js` or cli ? or just use coding, not using `application` like this below picture (using postman-apps), so everytime i run the program, it will trigger and push to that localhost rather than using postman-apps. also so i know how it works because this postman is a simulation right?

[image]

basicly I still lack of knowledge about this so I don't really know what is this postman, is this like a server then does `get.req` ? or something, I was searching a lot but also I really have no idea. I will be happy if you show me some sources too for me to learn this.

because this postman apps only input `http://localhost:3333...` and then somehow there are some `JSON` from the apps itself created ? anyway just answer my very first question, probably i will understand later, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I learnt it, it was REST-API things